# Yii - Populate CDataProvider items into a Tree format

Tags: data-binding, yii, yii-components

I have a view showing a sports tournament draw. It is in a typical tree format - 32 contestants reducing to half every round (see image). I have the data coming down in the form of CDataProvider with each item  having the name and the position in the tree. How do you suggest I go about it?

[image: The static version of the intended view]

Currently each record would contain information like - 
- Name of the player (players, in case of doubles)
- Draw position - match 1, player 1; match 1 player 2 and so on
- Status, if the match has been played (and the score is available elsewhere ...)

Since the number of fields in the tree is fixed for a 32 player draw, I have created the placeholders as div tags with names as pos_01_1, pos_01_2, pos_02_1, pos_02_2, and so on. I am ready to scrap this approach if there is a more elegant approach. The tree has been built using a 64x6 table with some of the cells having border-right and border-bottom set as 'Solid 1px'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am finally able to display JSON data in a (reverse-binary) tree-format. I have used D3.js to create SVG elements based on the total-nodes, total-depth. Again, I am using D3.js to populate Text elements on each node with the player-names, seed. My working solution can be seen [**here**](http://tallyho.in/apps/index.php/tour/category/draw/view/id/13) -

In short, the dataProvider is substituted by an array, which is returned from `findAllByAttributes` method. Then the array values are JSONified before being consumed by the D3.js SVG plot.